# Integral involves trigonometric function , need help

Tags: calculus, integration

Integrat : $\frac{1}{5(\sin(x))^2-1}$

I try to rewrite denominator as :

$4(\sin(x))^2-(\cos(x))^2=(2\sin(x)-(\cos(x)) * (2\sin(x)+\cos(x))$

But I couldn't go further, any help please

Comment: Hint : Try using formula for cos(2x) (double angle formula) and then the standard integral technique for 1/(a+bcosx)

Comment: Try using $\sin\theta=\frac{\tan\theta}{\sec\theta}$ and the Pythagorean identity.  Then with a $u$-substitution you should end up factoring the denominator and decomposing into partial fractions.

Comment: @user474986 can you write first steps please ,  thanks  a lot

Answer (score 1):

I will give you just the push needed to solve the integral.

$$\int \frac{1}{5\sin^2 x -1} dx$$

Using double angle formula, you get :

$$=\int \frac{2}{3 -5\cos(2x)} dx$$

Now substitute $\tan(x)=t$ and proceed. Do you reach a standard indefinite integral?